# how to send a message with a followup in actions-on-google

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to inform my customer before moving them to a followup intent. I can call each intent individually, and when I call Injured it takes me to the "Send Care Package" intent, but it never responds with the "I'm sorry to hear that" text. I've also tried with conv.close() but I can't get it to say something before forwarding to the 2nd intent.

I'm using the actions-on-google-nodejs package

```
app.intent('Injured', conv => {
    conv.ask("I'm sorry to hear that")
    conv.followup('event2')
})

app.intent('Send Care Package', conv => {
    //send care package
    conv.close("I'm sending you a care package")
})
```

Comment: Can you also update your question to include screen shots of the Dialogflow Intents you mention, including the sample phrases and parameters?

Comment: I got my answer from Github.  This feature is not possible as the "followup" event is nothing more than an internal redirect within the backend.  It never sends anything back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to do this using Dialogflow (formerly known as API.AI). You would have to create User Intents with a response, then trigger your next (follow-up) response afterwords.